# Xamarin.forms | Grouped ListView | Remove Separator line below Group section title/cell | iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, sectionheader, grouped-table

I am developing a grouped listview in xamarin.forms, I have removed separator lines between listview cell by setting SeparatorVisibility property to None. But white separator line below group section cell still exists. There is no property exposed to remove that line. I am currently testing for iOS version. How can I remove that line below group cell. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks 
[Screesnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOTWr.png)

Comment: _But white separator line below group section cell_ - do you mean group header? Also, some code example will be a plus )

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, I know, but if anybody faced this issue, setting  `SeparatorVisibility="None"` **&** `SeparatorColor="Transparent"` did the trick for me.